# How to code this on numpy

Tags: python, numpy

raster, raster_B8a_166 - numpy array (xsize / xsize)

```
for i in range(xsize):
    for j in range(xsize):
        if raster[i][j] == 166 and raster_B8a_166[i][j]:
            raster[i][j] = 39
        elif raster[i][j] == 166 and raster_B8a_166[i][j] == False:
            raster[i][j] = 11
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example on two 1D arrays. The same code should apply to a pair of 2D arrays.

Note that with numpy arrays  a == 166 will return a Truth array with the same shape as a. Then logical_and takes two truth arrays, performs a logical and, and returns a third truth array. Finally you can return or set specific items in a numpy array by feeding a truth array into it.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 166, 166])
b = np.array([True, False, True, False])

a[np.logical_and((a == 166), (b == True))] = 39
a[np.logical_and((a == 166), (b == False))] = 11

print(a)
```